# you are attempting to define UNSAFE_componentWillMount on your component more than once

Tags: react-native

i try to upgrade ReactNative from 0.50.4->0.66.4,it makes error during reload:

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
WARN  Require cycle: src/store/index.js -> src/reducers/index.js -> src/reducers/NavigationReducer.js -> src/router/rootNavigation/navigationConfiguration.js -> src/router/caStackNavigation/CAStackNavigation.js -> src/router/caStackNavigation/navigationConfiguration.js -> src/screens/AddScreen.js -> src/components/jiedai/TouxiangItem.js -> src/components/common/index.js -> src/components/common/Container.js -> src/utils/AppWatermarkView.js -> src/store/index.js

Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: ReactClassInterface: You are attempting to define `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` on your component more than once. This conflict may be due to a mixin.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by upgrading the `create-react-class` package from 15.6.2 to 15.6.3 (or higher)

For more details please visit [this issue page](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12830)